# Identify name of connector

Tags: identification, connector

What is the name of the connector in the attached file?

[image]

Comment: Please properly crop your picture and provide dimensions.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://connectorbook.com/identification.html

Comment: I do'nt know the size but is the same as this one: https://he.aliexpress.com/item/1005002263621922.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.3.22a9xrz6xrz6A2&algo_pvid=b271c911-a44c-42f7-a0c8-3dbaa6ea6565&algo_exp_id=b271c911-a44c-42f7-a0c8-3dbaa6ea6565-1&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000019808018642%22%7D&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21ILS%219.69%216.6%21%21%21%21%21%402100b1a616787068391627426d06fd%2112000019808018642%21sea%21IL%212339186971&curPageLogUid=ArBHlVxP0Rbt

Comment: I would be a good idea if you took a photo where the focus was on the connector, not the cables! :D Also, more than one photo, from different angles. Finally, what's the pitch of the pins?

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely a clone of the following connector:

Manufacturer: JST (Japan Solderless Terminals)

Manufacturer part number header: S3B-PH-SM4-TB

Manufacturer part number housing: PHR-3

Datasheet: [PH connector](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/ePH.pdf?640f1b32baf98)

Header SMT side entry type

[image: Header SMT side entry type]

Housing

[image: Housing]